# Streaming results using Rust actix-web, lifetime issue

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream, actix-web

I am having issue to use `Stream` with actix-web using bellow code:

```rust
fn format_csv_row(row: tiberius::Row) -> Result<web::Bytes, ServerError> { ... }

#[get("/stream/")]
async fn get_stream(
    db_pool: web::Data<bb8::Pool<TiberiusConnectionManager>>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, ServerError> {
    // Get connection
    let mut conn = db_pool
        .get()
        .await
        .map_err(|e| ServerError::PoolUnavailable)?;

    // Execute query
    let stream = conn
        .query("SELECT * FROM table", &[])
        .await
        .map_err(|e| ServerError::QueryFail)?;

    // Build a stream from SQL results
    let stream = stream.map(|x| format_csv_row(x.unwrap()));
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().streaming(stream))
}
```

Here are the methods I call in this function:

- [bb8::Pool::get](https://docs.rs/bb8/0.7.0/bb8/struct.Pool.html#method.get)
- [tiberius::Client::query](https://prisma.github.io/tiberius/tiberius/struct.Client.html#method.query)
- [actix-web::HttpResponseBuilder::stream](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/dev/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.streaming)

The compiler complains with the following errors:

```
error[E0597]: `db_pool` does not live long enough
   --> src/routes/trades_stream.rs:88:20
    |
88  |       let mut conn = db_pool
    |                      -^^^^^^
    |                      |
    |  ____________________borrowed value does not live long enough
    | |
89  | |         .get()
    | |______________- argument requires that `db_pool` is borrowed for `'static`
...
102 |   }
    |   - `db_pool` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `conn` does not live long enough
   --> src/routes/trades_stream.rs:94:18
    |
94  |       let stream = conn
    |                    -^^^
    |                    |
    |  __________________borrowed value does not live long enough
    | |
95  | |         .query("SELECT * FROM table", &[])
    | |__________________________________________- argument requires that `conn` is borrowed for `'static`
...
102 |   }
    |   - `conn` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I understand that connection and pool are dropped while streaming is still in progress.

How can I modify my code to make this works ?
Is it possible to add explicit lifetime for `db_pool` and `conn` to make them match `stream` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work, we need to change the code such that the stream has ownership of the connection it is reading from, and due to how bb8 is written, you also need ownership of a handle to the pool. The best way to do this is to use the [`async-stream`](https://docs.rs/async-stream) crate.

I believe something like this should do it:

```
use async_stream::try_stream;

fn format_csv_row(row: tiberius::Row) -> Result<web::Bytes, ServerError> { ... }

#[get("/stream/")]
async fn get_stream(
    db_pool: web::Data<bb8::Pool<TiberiusConnectionManager>>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, ServerError> {
    // Cloning a bb8 pool gives a new handle to the same pool.
    let db_pool = db_pool.clone();

    let stream = try_stream! {
        // Get connection
        let mut conn = db_pool
            .get()
            .await
            .map_err(|e| ServerError::PoolUnavailable)?;

        // Execute query
        let stream = conn
            .query("SELECT * FROM table", &[])
            .await
            .map_err(|e| ServerError::QueryFail)?;

        while let Some(row) = stream.next().await {
            yield format_csv_row(row?)?;
        }
    };

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().streaming(Box::pin(stream)))
}
```

You might need another `map_err` on the `row?` part.

> Is it possible to add explicit lifetime for db_pool and conn to make them match stream ?

No, you don't change how long things live by setting lifetimes. Instead, you change the lifetimes by changing the structure of the code in a way such that it lives long enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not know this crates exists.

I think it is getting closer to work but I still got an error:
`within AsyncStream<std::result::Result<actix_web::web::Bytes, _>, impl futures::Future>, the trait Unpin is not implemented for from_generator::GenFuture<[.......]>`

Do you think it can be fixed using this crates ? Or shoud I refactor this code differently ?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. The fix is easy, just add `Box::pin` around the stream.

Comment: It now successfully build. I will need more time to check if it works well. Then, I will edit and update my original post with few changes I have made to your suggession.

Comment: I have also found this related issue that might works https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1690 but I feel `async_stream` is more clear.